# Set custom 401 error view in Windows Authentication mode for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, windows-authentication

My MVC application is set on Windows Authentication mode.

I would like to provide a custom 401 error view/page when a not-authorized user trying to access some resource at my app instead of the default IIS page.

I'm decorating my `Action` with the following Attributes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorized(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Add()
{
  return View();
}
```

How can I do it in MVC?

Thank you,